# I got same number every time in with python random.randint

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, python-3.8

Help!

My script is

```
import random 
rnumb = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
while 3>2:
   print(rnumb)
```

if i run this code got only one same number

ps. I use python 3.8

Comment: Put `rnumb = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)` *inside* the `while` loop.

Comment: Why pick an arbitrary condition that's true, instead of just writing `while True:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are generating a random number only once, then printing it indefinitly.

```
import random 
while 3>2:
   rnumb = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
   print(rnumb)
```

will work better.